# Javascript - BST (Balanced and unbalanced trees) find In-Order Predecessor

Tags: javascript, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

The function takes the root node of a binary tree and a target value and returns the node that comes before the target value in an in-order traversal.

Constraint is:
If the target is the first value in an in-order traversal, return null.

```
function inOrderPredecessor(rootNode, target) {
  if (rootNode === null || rootNode.val === target) {
    return null
  }

  if (rootNode.left) {
    current = rootNode.left;
    while(current.right != null) {
      current = current.right;
    }
    return current.val;
  }

}
```

I've been working on this for hours and I keep hitting my head against a wall. An embarassingly long amount of time.. Over 4 hours watching  videos etc.

The function can ONLY take in the rootNode and the target value.

Psuedo Code I have been thinking -

1. Start at left of rootNode since predecessor is always smaller.
2. From first left go right, until you can't go right anymore.
3. Return right most item when there are no more rights to take.

Comment: Am I dumb or couldn't you just do an in-order traversal and find the index of the target...?

Comment: Mind showig me? I can do in order traversals: 

inOrderTraversal(currentNode = this.root) {
    // Your code here
    if (currentNode === null) return;

    if (currentNode.left) {
      this.inOrderTraversal(currentNode.left)
    }

    console.log(currentNode.val)

    if (currentNode.right) {
      this.inOrderTraversal(currentNode.right)
    }
    return;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive approach, that usually makes trees easier to handle:

```
function inOrderPredecessor(node, target) {
  if (node === null) {
    return null
  }
  if (target <= node.val) {
    // the node lies to the right of, or at the target value
    // so we need to find a node that precedes the target from the left child tree
    return inOrderPredecessor(node.left, target);
  } else { // target > node.val
    // the node lies to the left of the target value (and would qualify)
    // but there might be a node in its right child tree that is closer
    // (but not larger than or equal to the target)
    const res = inOrderPredecessor(node.right, target);
    if (res) {
      // if there is, return it
      return res;
    } else {
      // otherwise return the node itself
      return node;
    }
  }
}
```

It is also possible to write this with a loop that turns left and right, but not quite as straightforward:

```
function inOrderPredecessor(node, target) {
  var candidate = null;
  while (node) {
    if (node.val < target) {
      candidate = node;
      node = node.right;
    } else {
      node = node.left;
    }
  }
  return candidate;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I ended up having a friend help me. One of the test cases used an unordered BInary Tree (The rest were BST) so I was having a lot of trouble. Her solution, like yours, was with recursion. 

She didn't add an itertative function, so I do appreciate that. My iterative function is WILDLY longer than yours.

To get it to work, I did have to change one line ---> candidate = node.val

Thank you every much for the two solutions as well as the explainations. Recursion is hard when you're first starting out. Makes brain go bzzzt. 

Thanks for your time + explaination! <3

Comment: The only reason I ahd to change that piece of code was some reason the test was requiring the node value instead of the node object(even though it said the opposite!)

Answer (score 0):

Collect the traversed nodes into an array, then search the array and return the node before the target:

```js
// simple inorder traversal implementation
function inorder(node, a = []) {
    if (node) {
        inorder(node.left, a);
        a.push(node);
        inorder(node.right, a);
    }
    
    return a;
}

const tree = {
    value: 4,
    left: { value: 2, left: { value: 1 }, right: { value: 3 } },
    right: { value: 5 },
};

// show that the tree values are already in order
console.log(inorder(tree).map((node) => node.value));

// return node that was before the target
function predecessor(node, target) {
    const traversed = inorder(node);
    
    return traversed[traversed.indexOf(target) - 1];
}

// should be 3, since tree.value is 4, and 3 is before 4
console.log(predecessor(tree, tree));
```

Comment: It's returning undefined. If you'd like, check out my github, it has all the test cases etc. The problem itself is in tree-practice.js --- https://github.com/ChrisCarucci/AppAcademy_BinaryTree_Project

Comment: That's quite inefficient.